# ANTLR: Define new channel in grammar

Tags: antlr, token, grammar, antlr3

I know it is possible to switch between the default and hidden token channels in an ANTLR grammar, but lets say I want a third channel. How can I define a new token channel in the gramar?  For instance, lets say I want a channel named ALTERNATIVE.

Comment: For anyone coming here in 2022 (I have 4.10) and being nonplussed about why the "channel name" trick as described in the ANTLR book is not accepted ("foo is not a recognized channel name" says ANTLR) see https://github.com/antlr/antlr4/issues/1555 - Custom channel names are no longer allowed in combined grammars (so use integers instead) and in lexer grammars, the syntax to define them is now `channels { FOO }`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They're just `final int`'s in the [`Token` class](http://www.antlr.org/api/Java/interfaceorg_1_1antlr_1_1runtime_1_1_token.html)
, so you could simply introduce an extra `int` in your lexer like this:

```
grammar T;

@lexer::members {
  public static final int ALTERNATIVE = HIDDEN + 1;
}

// parser rules ...

FOO
  :  'foo' {$type=ALTERNATIVE;}
  ;

// other lexer rules ...
```

A related Q&A: [How do I get an Antlr Parser rule to read from both default AND hidden channel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741829/how-do-i-get-an-antlr-parser-rule-to-read-from-both-default-and-hidden-channel)

Answer (score 1):

For the C target you can use

```
//This must be assigned somewhere
@lexer::context {
  ANTLR3_UINT32 defaultChannel;
}

TOKEN : 'blah' {$channel=defaultChannel;};
```

This gets reset after every rule so if you want a channel assignment to persist across rules you may have to override nextTokenStr().